# Input search is changing text color to black on mouse leave

Tags: html, css

I´m trying to devellop a search input but I´m having an issue and I´m not finding a way to resolve my problem.

I already have the input search working, when I click in the input it expands, but When the input expands and then I write, I write text with white color and I want that like this.

But then when I click outside the input text color is black and I also wanted it to be white or gray.

Anyone there know how we can do this with CSS? On mouse leave the color be white and not black?

**My codePen file:**

http://codepen.io/mib/pen/saytl/

**My html:**

```
 <li id="sb-search" style="float:right; list-style:none; height:20px;">
     <form id="search">                   
       <input name="q" type="text" size="40" placeholder="Pesquisar..." />             
      </form>
 </li>
```

**My CSS:**

```
#search input[type="text"] {
    border: 0 none;
    font:  12px 'bariol_boldbold';
    background: #141d22;
        text-indent: 0;
    width:110px;
    padding: 6px 15px 6px 35px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 20px;
    -moz-border-radius: 20px;
    border-radius: 20px;
    text-shadow: 0 2px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3); 
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 1px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1), 0 1px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2) inset;
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 1px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1), 0 1px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2) inset;
    box-shadow: 0 1px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1), 0 1px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2) inset;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.7s ease 0s;
    -moz-transition: all 0.7s ease 0s;
    -o-transition: all 0.7s ease 0s;
    transition: all 0.7s ease 0s;
    }

#search input[type="text"]:focus {
    background: #141d22;
    color: #fff;
    width: 170px;
        outline:none;
        color:000;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 1px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1), 0 1px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.9) inset;
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 1px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1), 0 1px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.9) inset;
    box-shadow: 0 1px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1), 0 1px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.9) inset;
    text-shadow: 0 2px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
    }
```

Comment: Do you not just want it white always?

Comment: You can simply set the color to be white always as Anthony mentioned.. Otherwise since there's no `mouse leave` selector in css, you'll have to use js..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `color:#ffffff`  to `#search input[type="text"]` and color will be white when mouse leave selector in css.

[***See demo***](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/AGtqf)

Comment: So simple how I didnt think about it! But thank you, it was exactly that I was trying!

Answer (score 1):

Add a white color to the input